# Reverse wiring basement lights

Tags: wiring

Can existing basement lights wired in succession from the main electric panel, with the last light on a switch be reverse wired so that all of the lights can be controlled by the switch?

Answer (score 4):

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "reverse wired?"

If you're saying you want to put the switch at the far end, near the last light,the most straightforward way to do that is to pull power into that switch box, then feed the lights from there (don't feed the lights directly from the panel).

Or, I suppose you could pull 3-rope all the way through from the first light to the last light. You'd run 2-rope from the panel to the first light.

**EDIT:** a commentor pointed out that code now requires a neutral in all switch boxes. So run 3-rope from the last light fixture to the switch box, use the red and black for your switch leg, and cap the neutral for future use (presence-detecting switches and so on).

Connect the black wire straight through all the light fixture boxes. Then connect the switch leg (the 3-rope running from the last light fixture to the switch) to the black and red wires. At each light fixture, pigtail and connect the red (hot) and white (neutral) to each light fixture. Or you could switch black and red (wire red straight through, wire black to each fixture)--doesn't matter.

You always want to switch the hot wire, not the neutral. Otherwise, you end up with power at the fixtures even when the switch is off and it's a shock hazard.

I'm not sure why I feel compelled to say this, but if the lights in question are all on the same circuit, they should be wired in parallel (not in series), so the hot and neutral wires need to be pigtailed in the box at each light fixture to connect to each light, but also run directly to the next light (not wired *through* each light to the next).

Comment: This 3-wire setup is exactly what I have in my basement, as wired by the builder. The same cable supplies power from the main panel at the other end of the basement, feeds several lights, goes to a switch at the entry point, *and* feeds a few outlets, too. Been in place for a few years, and hasn't failed yet.

Comment: Note that Code now requires a neutral at all switches, so a 2-rope to the switch from the last light doesn't comply. Run a 3-rope and leave the neutral capped for possible future smart switch use.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Yep, run 3-rope to the switch. Thanks!

Comment: Where the heck does referring to conductors as "rope" come from?? I've never heard that before, either on this site or from any actual contractor or electrician I've worked with.

Comment: @gregmac Wires bundled up in a sheath (like NM cable) is a cable. Cables have traditionally been called rope, going way back. I did some work for my electrician uncle when I was young and he and others referred to it that way, so that's what's in my head. 2 rope would be NM/Romex cable with two conductors (plus ground), 3 rope would be the cable with 3 conductors.

Comment: Although technically, of course, it's 14/2 or 12/2 (or whatever gauge) NM cable, or 14/3 or 12/3 MC or whatever. Which of course is more technically accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution would be to either run power and neutral to the switch and then run switched power and neutral back to the lights, or to run power/neutral to a box, run a "switch loop" from there to the switch and back, and then run switched power and neutral from box to lights.

It sounds like you want to do something different ... which may or may not work electrically (I don't understand your idea well enough to answer than)  but may not meet code.

Comment: Switches are for the "hot" conductors in regular AC applications. No switching neutrals.

Comment: Uhm.... didn't say anything about switching neutrals, just running neutral to complete the circuit. Or at least that was my intent;  it is Sunday night after all.